# conversion data calculations

Tags: javascript, data-conversion

Have a nice holiday and thank you for your help

I have already tried to solve my problem but I have not given enough information I will try to reformulate it

I want the output to be these numbers

```
input 14:1   output 141 
input 13:8   output 141
input 13:18   output 241 
input 18:13   output 291
```

the calculation is as follows
input 14:1  4+1 is not greater than 9 so the number one is the rest and we leave it at the end and add 14 before it   output 141

input 13:8 3 + 8 is greater than 9 (11) so I add 1 to 3 of them become 4 and 1 is the rest we add at the end  output 141

```
input 13:18   output 241 
input 18:13   output 291
```

trying to help me here is an example code they thank a woman from Germany for it

```
const
    fn = string => {
        const
            sum = (a, b) => (a + b).toString().padStart(2, 0).split(''),
            [a, b] = string.split(':').map(s => s.padStart(2, 0)),
            result = [];
 
        let i = 2;
        while (i--) {
            const sum = +a[i] + +b[i];
            result[i] = sum > 10
                ? +[+a[i] + Math.floor(sum / 10), sum % 10].join('')
                : sum === 10 ? 1 : sum;
        }
        return result.join('');
    };
    
 
console.log(fn('13:18')); // I want 241 correct output 241
console.log(fn('18:13')); // I want 291 correct output 291

console.log(fn('13:15')); //  I want 28 correct output 28
console.log(fn('15:13')); //  I want 28 correct output 28

console.log(fn('14:1')); // I want 141 bad output   15
console.log(fn('13:8')); // I want 141 correct output 141
console.log(fn('78:96')) // I want 174 bad output   "8694"
```

this code calculates some results correctly and some incorrectly

if less than 10 console.log (fn ('14: 1 ')); // I want this 141 output / gives a bad output "15"

Comment: explain how 13:18 is becoming 241

Comment: still confused...can you tell what's 289:356 would be?

Comment: @sandeep.kgp  13:18   (3+8=11) 10/1   this is how we divide the number if they are greater than 9  ( and add the rest to the next number, ie to 4) and finally 1 + 1 = 2    output 141

Comment: okay..so what's 78:96 gonna be?

Comment: @sandeep.kgp 8+6 = 14         4 ladies at the end   next 7+1=8+9 = 17   output  174

Answer (score 1):

As per the logic you've explained, and assuming the numbers will be max of 2 length.

P.S.   +(plus sign) prefix converts string to integer runtime

First Solution =>

```js
const fn = (string) => {
      const [a,b] = string.split(':').map(s=>s.padStart(2,0)), result=[];
      // for first position
      result[0] = +a[0] + +b[0];
      // for second position
      let secondIndexTotal =  (+a[1] + +b[1]).toString();

      result[1] = +secondIndexTotal > 9 ? (+a[1] + 
      +secondIndexTotal[0]).toString() + secondIndexTotal[1] : a[1]+b[1];

      return result.join('');
}

console.log(fn('13:18')); // output 241
console.log(fn('18:13')); // output 291

console.log(fn('13:15')); // output 235
console.log(fn('15:13')); // output 253

console.log(fn('14:1')); // output 141
console.log(fn('13:8')); // output 141
```

Updated Solution =>

```js
const fn = (string) => {
  const [a, b] = string.split(":").map((s) => s.padStart(2, 0)),
    result = [];
  // for second position
  const secondIndexTotal = (+a[1] + +b[1]).toString();

  result[1] = +secondIndexTotal > 9 ? secondIndexTotal[1] : b[1];

  // for first position
  const firstIndexTotal = +a[0] + +b[0];
  result[0] =
    firstIndexTotal > 9
      ? firstIndexTotal + (+secondIndexTotal > 9 ? +secondIndexTotal[0] : 0)
      : firstIndexTotal.toString() +
        (+a[1] + (+secondIndexTotal > 9 ? +secondIndexTotal[0] : 0));

  return result.join("");
};
console.log(fn("13:18")); // output 241
console.log(fn("18:13")); // output 291
console.log(fn("78:96")); // output 174
console.log(fn("14:1")); // output 141
console.log(fn("13:15")); // output 235
console.log(fn("15:13")); // output 253
```

Comment: `78:96          8+6 = 14 4 ladies at the end next 7+1=8+9 = 17 output 174 `   all results correct but this one does not  when I tried it  `console.log(fn('78:96')); give 1694`

Comment: console.log(fn('13:15')); // output 28
console.log(fn('15:13')); // output 28       if the results are 28 it will work perfectly  and console.log(fn('78:96')) //1694  want     174   otherwise it works perfectly just didn't diminish those numbers

Comment: could you do it I would be very grateful to you

Comment: What output do you want for console.log(fn('13:15'))?

Comment: `console.log(fn("13:15")); // output 28
console.log(fn("15:13")); // output 28`

Comment: What is the logic behind printing all this numbers?

Comment: count them from behind and increase to more than 9 to 1 more two numbers

`13:15 (3 + 5 = 8) 1 + 1 = 2 resolut is 28`